# default route through VPN tunnel

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn

Here we go again trying to make a friendship with Linux
I've installed ubuntu and I use remote VPN to connect to my workplace
I've used to use OpenVPN on windows and everything worked fine for me
Now on ubuntu

I have an internet connection with my default gateway of 192.168.0.1 (DHCP)

```
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlp8s0 proto dhcp metric 600
```

Now when I activate VPN (i just downloaded the same *.ovpn* file I used on Win) I lose internet connection and I figured out how. Somehow I receive a static (somehow) default route through my tun0 interface with better metric

```
default via *private_ip* dev tun0 proto static metric 50
```

Anyone please?

Comment: You can answer your own question. This isn't a forum so "solved" in the question should be avoided.

Comment: oh thanks. Actually I was about to delete this question, but thought that it can be useful

Answer (score 1):

solved by:

there's a checkbox in IPV4 tab of the VPN Settings

*Use this connection only for resources on this network*